# Edit Webpage tags using VBA

Tags: javascript, html, vba

I am trying to click a row of the table in webpage(it is IBM's JAZZ Server) using VBA
If I click on the row manually, the HTML code changes.(JavaScript).

The HTML webpage contains before I click the row:

```
<... class = "DropDownButton" ....>
```

The HTML webpage contains after I click the row:

```
<...class = "DropDownButtonPressed" ...>
```

The class name changes.I can't share the URL of the webpage because you should have an account.I want to click on the drop down button.I am able to click a button in the webpage using click function(Since they are just buttons and not drop down button).
This is what the page looks like. I want to click on the highlighted drop down button.
[image: Web Page]

Upon inspecting the webpage this is what you see :

[image: Highlighted is the drop down button]

Upon clicking the drop down this is how the web page changes:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this.Can anybody refer me to some resources or blogs where clicking on drop down button using VBA is discussed that would be helpful.Thanks a lot.

My code:

```
Sub BrowseToSite()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLIn As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
'URL$


'Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate "https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Jazz%20Collaborative%20ALM#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.newWorkItem&type=defect&ts=15279513017930&tab=com.ibm.team.workitem.tab.links"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Loop

'IE.Document.forms("searchform").elements("search").Value = "Sachin"

Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document

Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("DropdownArrow")

HTMLDoc.querySelector ("span[dojoattachpoint=""_dropdownArrow""]").Click // Nothing is hhappening



'Tried also with
    HTMLDoc.querySelector(".HTMLButtons").Click


End Sub
```

Comment: @QHarr I am afraid I can't share the URL.But the gist is this : I need to change the tag value of aria-selected to true.Thanks

Comment: @QHarr Thanks for the response.I have edited the question.Is this helpful? Can you deduce something? Please help.

Comment: @QHarr Can you tell me what is that $URL , do I have to import some library for that , since it is throwing an error.Do I have to download Selenium?

Comment: @QHarr Hey , I have edited the question as you told. I still don't have an idea what $URL is?

Comment: @QHarr Yes, its the same URL that I used in the code.But I think you need access. I can give you my username and password , if you want to have a look.

Comment: Absolutely do not give people, including me, your login details. Bit like handing a stranger your wallet. Don't do it. That aside, I hadn't noticed your code, did you just edit it in? I will have a look.

Comment: @QHarr I have only one item .It's length is one.It's innerHTML is   "   <span class="DropdownArrowElement"></span> ".It's innerText is empty string. And thanks for the upvote.

Comment: HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("DropdownArrow")(0).Click

Comment: Do you have access to jazz server .You can create a free account if you want to.It's IBM's Rational team concert ALM

Comment: @QHarr 'HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("DropdownArrow")(0).Click' I tried this before asking the question on StackOverflow.Not happening :(. Can they disable the click of that button by script so that it can only be done manually?

Comment: So it seems like we have the right element selected...are you familiar with inspecting for potentially associated javascript functions?

Comment: @QHarr Yes, we have selected the right element. No , I don't know how to look for the JS functions.When I saw the page source,the source file of javascript is around 1000 lines of code

Comment: It is possible to set DOM event listeners including break on click events using Chrome Dev tools (F12) - you can often use this to step through working out which, if any events, are linked to clicking a partic item. And then inspecting that event code for anything that can be targeted via VBA.

Comment: @QHarr I did what you suggested , a bunch of functions are being called but I am not sure how it's going to help? Can I do something in VBA by fetching Xpath of the element? and then performing click function.